# Visual Studio 2019 xUnit Testing Error CS0246

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to create unit tests, after adding a new project with an xUnit test template I added a reference to the project I want to test. I keep running into this error.

```
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Book' 
could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I have Book defined so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

Comment: Have you included the namespace it's defined in in the test class file?

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich
Not explicitly, no. In the csproj file there is a reference to the project that contains the Book class.

Comment: You gotta add that.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help.